# Manual commit in Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, django-models

How do you implement `@commit_manually` in Django 1.8?

I'm trying to upgrade Django 1.5 code to work with Django 1.8, and for some bizarre reason, the `commit_manually` decorator was removed in Django 1.6 with no direct replacement. My process iterates over thousands of records, so it can't wrap the entire process in a single transaction without running out of memory, but it still needs to group some records in a transaction to improve performance. To do this, I had a method wrapped with @commit_manually, which called transaction.commit() every N iterations.

I can't tell for sure from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/#transactions), but this still seems supported. I just have to call `set_autocommit(False)` instead of having a convenient decorator. Is this correct?

Answer (score 8):

Yeah, you've got it. Call `set_autocommit(False)` to start a transaction, then call `commit()` and `set_autocommit(True)` to commit it.

You could wrap this up in your own decorator:

```
def commit_manually(fn):
    def _commit_manually(*args, **kwargs):
        set_autocommit(False)
        res = fn(*args, **kwargs)
        commit()
        set_autocommit(True)
        return res
    return _commit_manually
```

Comment: thanks, works like a charm! But I prefer to use rollback instead of commit after calling the function and also call the function inside a try except block.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid `commit_manually` and re-write it to `atomic()`:

```
try:
    with atomic():
        return try_to_update_data(...)
except UpdateFailed:
    pass

... here goes futher handling of "failed"
```

```
class UpdateFailed(Exception):
    pass
```

```
def try_to_update_data(...): 
    ...
    ...
    if ok:
        return ...
    raise UpdateFailed()
```

I know (and follow) the rule of thumb "Don't use exceptions for control flow". But in this case, I think it is fine.